# How is damage by pulling sideways usually addressed in connectors?

Tags: connector

Looks like the primary goal of [Magsafe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magsafe) is to prevent damage to the connector (both the mobile part and device-attached part) from pulling the connector sideways. Wikipedia cites a patent issued in 2007.

That puzzles me. Isn't the problem at least several decades old? For example, Micro-USB seems to be designed for mobile devices and is super tiny and it's a result of many years of connectors evolution, so I guess the problem of pulling sideways should have been addressed there.

What are typical ways to mitigate risk of pulling sideways in connectors design?

Comment: The original point of Magsafe was so that if someone tripped over your laptop power cable it didn't send your laptop flying across the room to shatter into little pieces all over the floor.  The sideways thing was a knock-on bonus effect.

Comment: Micro-USB isn't that good at the sideways pull problem. For exhibit A, I present my previous cellphone. The USB port didn't survive me rolling over in bed while reading ebooks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That problem is normally solved by not having clumsy users yank at the cable at the wrong angle.

Most users are clumsy or have clumsy children or clumsy pets, so it's not a very good solution to rely on an absolute clumsy-free environment for your connectors.

Before magsafe there was one solution to clumsy users and that was to beef up the connectors and the cables to the point where the user was the one damaged in stead of the connector.

Answer (score 2):

Many connector systems are designed to (usually) pull out cleanly mechanically or are locked to (usually) prevent pull out. When "usually" is not good enough magnetic latching provides one option. It is not a new one - it has been in use in deep fryers for a decade or few and in other forms patents are available for decade back,. eg magnetic battery pull off terminal patent in 1989.

---

Magsafe was discussed in [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/20301/how-is-a-connector-with-only-edge-contacts-as-in-magsafe-practically-possible) - not the same as the current one but useful.

Patents may be obtained for a vast range of aspects of a product and the patent that Magsafe has does not cover the basic principle of magnetically retained pull away cords.

Magnetic pull away cords have been standard fare on domestic deep fryers in the US for a decade or two. So much so that [this page](http://www.ehow.com/how_6018174_magnetic-power-cord-deep-fryer.html) tells you how to find the correct one of many for your fryer,

Here's a typical one, but they come in many forms.

[image]

I saw a hot water jug in a Taiwan hotel room in 2001 that had a magnetic pull off power cord.

Many more available .... Ask [Alibaba  :-)](http://shuner.en.alibaba.com/productshowimg/459624987-210026730/UL_Power_Cord_Plug_Magnetic.html)

[image]